# OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener's callbacks aren't called during turn based match

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

```
@Override
public void onTurnBasedMatchRemoved(String matchId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTurnBasedMatchRemoved");
    Toast.makeText(this, "onTurnBasedMatchRemoved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onInvitationReceived");
    Toast.makeText(this, "onInvitationReceived", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Have code like this in my android application which is supposed to be called on other player's turn, what happens perfectly on my nexus 4 (android 5.0) and 5 (android 5.1), but on Xiaomi redmi node 2 (MIUI 7 build 5.9.24, Android 5.0.2 LRX22G) it doesn't happen. From the similar questions it seems like some phone specific problem. I did almost everything like "auto sync" option, recreating google play account and so on, but still no solution has been found. May be someone of you found it, how to make it work.

Google Play version 3.7.24 (3051774-048)

play-services dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn on synchronization in android settings